# how to fix UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcae' in position 1: surrogates not allowed on blender 3.6

Tags: blender, x3d

When I import the .x3d file into blender 3.6 to edit, I get this error. Can someone tell me how to fix it? thank you

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_x3d\__init__.py", line 60, in execute
    return import_x3d.load(context, **keywords)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_x3d\import_x3d.py", line 3629, in load
    load_web3d(context, filepath,
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_x3d\import_x3d.py", line 3498, in load_web3d
    root_node, msg = x3d_parse(filepath)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_x3d\import_x3d.py", line 1436, in x3d_parse
    doc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(data, parser)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\python\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 2003, in parseString
    return _do_pulldom_parse(pulldom.parseString, (string,),
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\python\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1981, in _do_pulldom_parse
    toktype, rootNode = events.getEvent()
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\python\lib\xml\dom\pulldom.py", line 266, in getEvent
    self.parser.feed(buf)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\python\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 217, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcae' in position 1: surrogates not allowed
```

im trying many time but same error

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a non utf-8 symbol in the file that blender can't handle try converting the x3d file to a blend file directly.
Here's a converter: https://imagetostl.com/convert/file/x3d/to/blend

Hope this fixes your problem